# Does this SQL pick up ALL records or the LATEST record?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

the SQL below is designed to pull in all Opportunities related to the Opportunities in my Journey Source Data Extension to determine whether the Contact has met the Goal or not.

There are criteria in a decision split before the first email is sent that checks whether 'Number_of_finished_requests__c is greater than 0'. If true, then don't send the email and exit. If false, continue through the journey.

My question is in this SQL would the field 'Number_of_finished_requests__c' look at ALL Opportunities related to the Contact ALL-TIME, or only the latest Opportunity related to the Contact in the Journey right now?

My feeling is that it's looking at ALL-TIME, but I need it to look at the Opp from the journey.

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
SELECT
 de.[Request__c:Booker_Contact__r:Id] as "Id"
, de.[Request__c:Booker_Contact__r:Email] as "Email"
, de.[Request__c:Opportunity__r:Name] as "OpportunityName"
, opp.NumberOfRequests__c as "NumberofRequests"
, opp.StageName
, opp.Id as 'OpportunityID'
, opp.Number_of_finished_requests__c
, request.Status__c

FROM Opportunity_Salesforce opp
LEFT JOIN [DE_22_0_request_accepted_journey] de
ON de.[Request__c:Opportunity__r:Name] = opp.Name

LEFT JOIN Request__c_Salesforce request
ON opp.Id = request.Opportunity__c

WHERE
de.[Request__c:Opportunity__r:Name] IS NOT NULL AND
(request.Status__c = 'Paid' OR
request.Status__c = 'Finished' OR
request.Status__c = 'Booked' OR
request.Status__c = 'Cancelled' OR
request.Status__c = 'Declined')
```

Comment: You’re matching on opportunity name and there are no date restrictions in your query. It would be much better to match on opportunity id and make the Journey DE your primary table (now the SF Opp table is the primary one).

Comment: Thank you. So would the following work? How would I make the date restriction say "after Journey OPP is created" for example? FROM [DE_22_0_request_accepted_journey] de 
LEFT JOIN Opportunity_Salesforce opp
ON de.[Request__c:Opportunity__r:Id] = opp.Id

Comment: The above looks good, please try it out and see if you are getting the results you need.